# Not getting Titlle,image and description first time when sharing URL to facebbok

Tags: php, joomla, facebook-opengraph

My website is on Joomla, [this is one page of my site](http://charteryacht.eu/index.php/49/28-09-2015/test).

Problem is when I create a new classified `Item` on my site and share it then I am not having right `image`, `title` and `desc` but when I go to FB Debugger and Scrap the data and then go back to site and again share it then I am getting the right `image`,`title` and `desc`.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The link you have provided generates a SQL error.